# Math in echo inside FOR loop

Tags: math, for-loop, batch-file, echo

I have a FOR loop in a batch file where in I print the counter value in echo statement. Sample code below:

```
SET cycles= (%%n+1) ****here n is a variable of value 1

for /l %%n in (1,1,%iterations%) do (
echo This is Iteration no: (%%n+%cycles%)
)
```

This is not working as it does not calculate and rather it says

> For was not expected this time

I tried with (%%n+%%cycles) also but it does not work. What can I try next?

Comment: You should show us what output do you expect, as your style is not clear (to me).  Do you expect that `%cycles%` will be executed/calculated never/once/every loop?

Comment: Unlike in other languages, there is no general math in `cmd` which would work for random commands like `echo`. `Set /a` is the *only* thing that does (some) math. So you have to calculate *first*, *then* `echo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply fails, as you use parenthesis in your echo statement!

You have to escape them, as the closing bracket closes the FOR loop.
The same problem you get, when you expand the `cycle` variable with percent, better use the delayed expansion, as the content will not be parsed any more.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET cycles= (%%n+1) ****here n is a variable of value 1
set iterations=5

for /l %%n in (1,1,%iterations%) do (
    echo This is Iteration no: (%%n+!cycles!^)
)
```

**EDIT:** A *calculating* version

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET cycles= (%%n+1)
set iterations=5

set "cyclesEscape=!cycles:)=^)!"
for /l %%n in (1,1,%iterations%) do (
    set /a result=%cyclesEscape%
    echo This is Iteration no: %%n Formula !cycles!=!result!
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this does not actually add and print the value. Rather it prints like 1+2, 2+3 etc... it does not do the math calculation.

Comment: The problem is, that you don't say what do you expect

Comment: I dont think so... my heading for this question clearly says that. "math in echo"... :)..